# Gradle include classes from Source set in a gradle test suite

Tags: java, gradle

I have this setup in my build.gradle:

```
testing {
    suites {
        test {
            useJUnitJupiter()
        }

        itest(JvmTestSuite) {
            testType = TestSuiteType.INTEGRATION_TEST

            dependencies {
                implementation project()
            }

            configurations {
                itestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
                itestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
                itestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
            }
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    testcommons{
        java{
            srcDir 'src/testcommons/java'
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to include test commons in both test suites, any idea how I can go on about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the output of the `testcommons` SourceSet as a dependency of the main suite:

```
testing {
   suites {
      test {
         dependencies {
            implementation(sourceSets["testcommons"].output)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note this approach eagerly accesses the `testcommons` SourceSet, so its definition must be moved above this code.